# How to manipulate the key of array of object into ngfor in angular 8

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects which needs to manipulate using ngFor as per the static html.I have already tried but not working so I commented.Value of 'mainitem' will come as a heading and key of 'Seconditem' will come inside li tag.Here is the code below and demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eigvsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
 <!--
    <div>
        <ul>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of jsonarray | keyvalue">
                <h5>{{item.key}}</h5>
                <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.value">
                    {{subItem.Order}}
                </li>
            </ng-container>
        </ul>
    </div>
     -->
    <div>
        <ul>
            <h5>My item 1</h5>
            <li>createddate</li>
            <li>enddate</li>
            <h5>My item 2</h5>
            <li>origindate</li>
            <li>startdate</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  jsonarray = [
    {
      mainitem: "My item 1",
      Seconditem: {
        createddate: "30-01-02",
        enddate: "30-01-03"
      }
    },
    {
      mainitem: "My item 2",
      Seconditem: {
        origindate: "30-01-04",
        startdate: "30-01-05"
      }
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a template that will work:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of jsonarray">
            <h5>{{item.mainitem}}</h5>
            <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.Seconditem | keyvalue">
                {{subItem.key}} - {{subItem.value}}
            </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</div>
```

link to working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uc15fx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this, I am finding some issues within your code, like the:

```
<li *ngFor="let subItem of item.value">
  {{subItem.Order}}
</li>
```

I cant seem to find within your item, a `item.value` nor a `.Order`

but I think you are overthinking it. (I think)

Try this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of jsonarray">
            <h5>{{item.mainitem}}</h5>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of item.Seconditem | keyvalue">
                
                {{subItem.key}} - {{subItem.value}}
            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I've provided **two options** for rendering the inner li's. You can choose one that suits your need.

HTML

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of jsonarray">
  <h5>{{item.mainitem}}</h5>
  <li *ngFor="let key of getKeys(item.Seconditem)">
    {{item.Seconditem[key]}}
  </li>
  <br>
  <li *ngFor="let value of getValues(item.Seconditem)">
    {{value}}
  </li>
</ng-container>
```

Add these functions in TS

```js
public getKeys(data){
  return Object.keys(data);
}
public getValues(data){
  return Object.values(data);
}
```

The approach I've shown here keeps your HTML super simple and manageable and is usually the recommended way for dealing with JSON objects that have non-uniform keys. Because, its always recommended to use **JS for data-manipulation** and let the HTMl deal **only with display**. Furthermore, we use the **Object** class which is a super powerful tool provided by Javascript itself! It comes with a ton of other useful functions (entries() is another great function which returns both key and value as an array! This could be of use for you too).
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

---

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any issues or questions.